# Difference between もう いい です and もう けっこう です

Tags: word-choice

I'm going back over my notes from Japanese For Busy People. I no longer have the books but I wrote out many of the examples. What I have not always done is write down my teacher's explanations. Hopefully I can get an answer here.

In these two examples we see けっこう and いい used.
I remember using けっこう for saying one does not want any more tea (いいえ、もう けっこう です) but I don't know if it is the same usage here.
More commonly I use もう いい です. So seeing けっこう here has confused me.

Could somebody explain the difference between these two examples please?

> 今 ペンが ありません。 えんぴつで も いい です か。
> はい、えんぴつで も けっこう です。
>
> 今 現金が ありません。 カードで も いい です か。
> はい、 カードで も いい です。

Comment: Did you notice that you are talking about もう いい・けっこう です, but the example sentences ～も いい・けっこう です don't use もう, but も?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are talking about two different (though related) shades of meaning of 「けっこう」 here.

> "no longer in need of ~~"

「もう**けっこう**です。」 means "I want no more ~~."

「もう**いい**です。」 has at least two meanings.  One is the same as 「もうけっこうです。」, but it is less formal than 「もうけっこうです。」.  The other meaning is "(Something) is ready to (or 'to be') ~~."

> "sufficient", "satisfactory", etc.

「えんぴつでも**けっこう**です。」 = "A pencil will suffice (if you have no pen)."

「カードでも**いい**です。」 = "A credit card would be no problem (if you do not have cash.)"  A store clerk would generally speak more formally than that and would say 「カードでも**けっこう**です。」

Comment: By the by, does 「もういいです。」 come off as rude to the listener? I get the impression that it's kinda blunt.

Comment: @akj: You are right. もういいです *can* mean "Enough (is enough)" depending on the context.